# Optimization when the function is not known, how generally it is performed?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I've a question on optimization (it is a general question).
I have a problem $P$ where basically i have the analytic expression of the objective function, which is a multivariate polynomial (positive), but i don't know all the constraints on the decision variables. There's a part where it is a linear system, while instead there is one constraints which is highly non linear and i can't derive neither the expression, however it is computable (i mean i can compute if such constraint hold's or not for a given decision variables).

Basically it is something like

$$\begin{equation}\left\{ \begin{array}{l} \vec{x}  = \text{argmin}_{\vec{x}} p_n(\vec{x}) \\ A\vec{x} \leq \vec{b} \\ \psi(\vec{x}) \leq \epsilon \\ \vec{x} \in U \subset \mathbb{Z}^n \end{array} \right.\end{equation} $$

It is of course a problem of integer programming, the set $U$ isn't that large (i.e. go through all the values of the variables is not that expensive) and the function $\psi(\cdot)$ is computationally expensive to compute. Just to clarify it is something of the form $\psi(\vec{x}) = \text{max}_{q \in V} g(\vec{x} ; q)$ where $V$ is a discrete but very large set.

My question is since basically the problem it is partially known (in terms of formula to be briefly) is there a specific way to study this kind of problem?

I basically need to find the max of $\psi(\cdot)$ in a fast way.
What kind of properties could i look for?
What kind of mathematical optimizations approach are there for this kind of problem?

Comment: Since $U$ isn't very large, can you just try every single point in $U$?  Would it be too expensive to evaluate $\Psi$  that many times?

Comment: Are the functions $g(\cdot, q)$ convex?  Are they differentiable?

Comment: Yes it would be expensive.

Comment: I would say it is definitely not differentiable, and that there is at least a $q$ such that $g(\cdot,q)$ is not convex.

Comment: All the problem however it is derived from floating point approximation and implementation of something. And so $\psi$ is related to error measurement, as far i know there isn't any kind of properties i could use to give a better analytic description of the problem, i would say that heuristic and combinatorial approach would fit better to the problem.

Comment: So... no suggestion? reference or whatever?

Comment: Not really, maybe someone else will have a suggestion.  How do you go about  evaluating $\Psi$?  And why do you say you need to "find the max" of $\Psi$ in a fast way, do you mean that you need to evaluate $\Psi$ in a fast way?

Comment: Yes actually the problem is the function psy in terms performance

Comment: But you don't need to maximize $\Psi $, you just need to evaluate it,  which requires maximizing $g(x, q)$ with respect to $ q $. What structure do $ g $ and $ V $ have?

Comment: It is something like (but not only that case)
$g(q ; \vec{x}) = \frac{f(q) - f_{approx}(q ; \vec{x})}{ulp(f(q))}$

Comment: while $V = \mathbb{F}(e,t)$ is basically a set of floating point number with $t$ mantissa bits and $e$ is exponent bits. So it is discrete evaluated, $f_{approx}$ isn't easy to describe since basically depends on the specific function (since basically you have to sum analytic error and algorithmic error, no representation error is taken into account since $V$ is a set of machine number. I don't know if these information could be useful or not. And moreover, it is true that i don't need to maximize $\psi$ but i have to maximize $g$... i don't see the difference.